# Wordpress - Update top-level parent publish date when a child is updated

Tags: php, wordpress, parent-child

I need to update the updated/published date of a top-level parent post when any child post is updated.

For example, if I have the structure:

- Parent Post

  - Child Post
  - Child Post 2

    - Grandchild post

If I update anything in the grandchild post, I need the Parent post to have it's published post to be 'now'. I think I can do this update_children, but I obviously haven't got it right, and this just duplicates the post thousands of times :s

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_children', 10, 2);
function update_children( $post_id, $post ) {
    $parents = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID );
    $root=count($parents)-1;
    $parent = $parents[$root];
    $time = date(Y-m-d);
    $my_post = array(
        'ID'           => $parent,
        'post_date'     => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $time ),
        'post_date_gmt' => get_gmt_from_date( $post_date ),
    );

    // Update the post into the database
    wp_update_post( $my_post );
}
```

Comment: How can a mere _update_ _"duplicate the post thousands of times"_?

Comment: How are you executing this function, did you bind it to any specific hook, or ...?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/O5OjkBC You tell me! @Cbroe

Comment: As for the function, yes sorry I missed that part. It was called in functions.php with add_action( 'save_post', 'update_children', 10, 2);

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/#avoiding-infinite-loops: _"If you are calling a function such as wp_update_post that includes the save_post hook, your hooked function will create an infinite loop. To avoid this, unhook your function before calling the function you need, then re-hook it afterward."_ - so that's probably what is causing your problem here.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try - does the code look like it should work other than that? I weren't sure if the way to get the top level parent ID was correct

Comment: `$root=count($parents)-1; $parent = $parents[$root];` - you are accessing the last item in what `get_post_ancestors` returned here - but I think that is the top-most page(?) You should access the first one, which is the parent of the current post. You update that parent - and that in turn then triggers the save_post hook again, so that your function will now update the parent of the parent of the original post ... and so on, until it has reached the top-most post.

Comment: And that top-most post will of course not have any parent(s) any more - so you should implement a check for that, otherwise you will be trying to update a `$parent` that is not existent next.

Comment: `'ID' => '$parent',` - and the single quotes around the variable are of course wrong here - right now, you would be passing the _literal text_ `$parent` here, instead of the actual value of the variable.